# Is there an equivalent to SetCursorPosition for a text stream?

Tags: c#, .net

when outputting to the console, you can set the specific location of the cursor and write to that (or use other nifty tricks like printing backspaces that will take you back.)

Is there a similar thing that can be done with a stream of text?

Scenario: I need to build a string with `n` pieces of, text where each might be on a different line and start position (or top and left padding).
Two strings might appear on the same line.

I could build a simple `Dictionary<int, StringBuilder>` and fidget with that, but I'm wondering if there's something like the console functionality for streams of text where you can write to a specific place (row and column).

**Edit:**
This is for a text only. No control.
The result might be a string with several new lines, and text appearing at different locations.

Example (where `.` will be white spaces):

```
..... txt3....... txt2
......................  
................ txt1.
```

this will be the result of having `txt1` at row 3 column (whatever), and `txt2` and `txt3` and row 1 with different colum values (where `txt3` column < `txt2` colmun)

Comment: You're basically describing List<char> (where you would track the insertion point yourself). I would not think List<char> would be a good structure for what you're describing, as inserting/deleting is quite inefficient. You'd be better off with a List<List<char>> or the like.

Comment: Could you please clarify: are you talking about string object (or StringBuilder) or some WPF UI control (like TextBox)? Best regards,

Comment: `FileStream` (among other streams) have a `Seek` method that allows you to set the position. However its not like an insert, when you seek a position it will overwrite at that position (kind of like the insert key being turned on and typing in a document). It also doesn't seek row/column, but a byte offset. This can be difficult to use depending on the encoding of the text data since a single character can be more than one byte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While waiting for a better answer, here's my solution. Seems to work, been lightly tested, and can be simply pasted into linqpad and run.

```
void Main()
{
    m_dict = new SortedDictionary<int, StringBuilder>();

    AddTextAt(1,40, "first");
    AddTextAt(2,40, "xx");
    AddTextAt(0,10, "second");
    AddTextAt(4,5, "third");
    AddTextAt(1,15, "four");

    GetStringFromDictionary().Dump();
}

// "global" variable
SortedDictionary<int, StringBuilder> m_dict;

/// <summary>
/// This will emulate writting to the console, where you can set the row/column and put your text there.
/// It's done by having Dictionary(int,StringBuilder) that will use to store our data, and eventually, 
/// when we need the string iterate over it and build our final representation.
/// </summary>
private void AddTextAt(int row, int column, string text)
{
    StringBuilder sb;

    // NB: The following will initialize the string builder !!
    // Dictionary doesn't have an entry for this row, add it and all the ones before it
    if (!m_dict.TryGetValue(row, out sb))
    {
            int start = m_dict.Keys.Any() ? m_dict.Keys.Last() +1 : 0;
        for (int i = start ; i <= row; i++)
        {
            m_dict.Add(i, null);
        }
    } 

    int leftPad = column + text.Length;
    // If dictionary doesn't have a value for this row, just create a StringBuilder with as many
    // columns as left padding, and then the text
    if (sb == null)
    {
        sb = new StringBuilder(text.PadLeft(leftPad));
        m_dict[row] = sb;
    }
    // If it does have a value:
    else
    {
        // If the new string is to be to the "right" of the current text, append with proper padding
        // (column - current string builder length) and the text
        int currrentSbLength = sb.ToString().Length;
        if (column >= currrentSbLength)
        {
            leftPad = column - currrentSbLength + text.Length;
            sb.Append(text.PadLeft(leftPad));
        }
        // otherwise, text goes on the "left", create a new string builder with padding and text, and 
        // append the older one at the end (with proper padding?)
        else
        {
            m_dict[row] = new StringBuilder(  text.PadLeft(leftPad)
                                            + sb.ToString().Substring(leftPad) );
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Concatenates all the strings from the private dictionary, to get a representation of the final string.
/// </summary>
private string GetStringFromDictionary()
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var k in m_dict.Keys)
    {
            if (m_dict[k]!=null)
            sb.AppendLine(m_dict[k].ToString());
            else
                sb.AppendLine();
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Output:

```
          second
               four                     first
                                        xx

     third
```

Answer (score 0):

No. Text files don't really have concept of horizontal/vertical position, so you'd need to build some sort of positioning yourself.

For basic positioning tabs (`"\t"`) may be enough, for anything more advanced you'd need to fill empty space with spaces.

It sounds like you have some sort of table layout - it may be easier to build data in cells first (`List<List<string>>` - list of rows consisting of columns of strings) and than format it with either `String.Format("{0}\t{1}\t...", table[row][0],table[row][1],...)` or manually adding necessary amount of spaces for each "cell"

Comment: i wasn't aware of any solution either. I've posted my workaround for this. weird that we don't have something like that ... isn't it?

Comment: @Noctis - there are likely libraries for that already - I'd search for "C# ascii art" as that is probably quite common reason to draw "pixels" at particular positions in text (also it is often generated by line directly from image).